# Unity Agora screenshare blurry video quality

Tags: unity-game-engine, agora.io

How to improve the image quality while sharing the screen using agora sdk with unity. I've used below
settings for VideoProfile as

```
mRtcEngine.SetVideoEncoderConfiguration(new VideoEncoderConfiguration()
{
    // Sets the video encoding bitrate (Kbps).
    minBitrate = 100,
    bitrate = 1130,
    // Sets the video frame rate.
    minFrameRate = 10,
    frameRate = FRAME_RATE.FRAME_RATE_FPS_24,
    // Sets the video resolution.
    dimensions = new VideoDimensions() { width = EncodeWidth, height = EncodeHeight },
    // Sets the video encoding degradation preference under limited bandwidth. MIANTAIN_QUALITY means to degrade the frame rate to maintain the video quality.
    degradationPreference = DEGRADATION_PREFERENCE.MAINTAIN_QUALITY,
    // Note if your remote user video surface to set to flip Horizontal, then we should flip it before sending
    mirrorMode = VIDEO_MIRROR_MODE_TYPE.VIDEO_MIRROR_MODE_ENABLED,
    // Sets the video orientation mode of the video
    orientationMode = ORIENTATION_MODE.ORIENTATION_MODE_FIXED_PORTRAIT
});
```

the Output from Editor to Device looks like below:

[image]

And Ouput from Device to Editor or another Deivce looks blurry as below:

[image]

Ive tested with WIFI on both device and ensure with good quality and also with forced settings as Image Quality than Frame Rate.

```
mRtcEngine.SetVideoQualityParameters(false);
mRtcEngine.EnableDualStreamMode(false);
mRtcEngine.SetRemoteDefaultVideoStreamType(REMOTE_VIDEO_STREAM_TYPE.REMOTE_VIDEO_STREAM_HIGH);
```

1. Do i missed anything else to improve the image quality?
2. How to share a Rect part of the screen and this rect can be draggable by user at part of the screen

Answer (score 0):

Blurry videos may be caused by low bitrates and resolution ratios. Check the following:

- Check videoProfile. If possible, set videoProfile to a higher level
  to see whether the video is clearer.
- Check the stream type of the receiver. If the stream type is low, call the setRemoteVideoStreamType method to switch from a low stream to high   stream. (You did this)
- Switch to another WiFi network to ensure that the blurry video is not caused by poor Internet connections.
- Turn off all pre-processing options.

If this issue persists, contact Agora customer support (via ticket system) with the following information:

- The uid of the user who sees the blurry video.
- The time frame during which the blurry video appears.
- SDK logs and screen recording files of the user.

You can check the statistics of every call in Agora Analytics in Dashboard.

Comment: Thansk @Rick, What is pre-processing options, could explain this?

Comment: That means custom jobs applied to the raw pixels, e.g., applying filters.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, also is the same from Agora FAQ page - https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/faq/video_blur. We'va proceed with the same as above settings itself as no other changes available except raising question to Agora team if client needs. Thanks